# Can an accept socket have a transient failure that's worth retrying?

Tags: sockets, boost-asio

This questions is primarily for boost::asio, but those on the `socket` tag will probably have some insight into transient failures regarding the `accept` call.

In Boost::Asio, if I have a socket acceptor coded to continuously accept new connections.

```
void Acceptor::StartNextAccept()
{
    // _acceptor is of type boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor

    _acceptor->async_accept([this](const boost::system::error_code& ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock) {
        if (ec)
        {
            // error
            LogErrorCode(ec);
        }
        else
        {
            // success
            HandleNewConnection(s);
        }

        StartNextAccept(); // enqueue another accept call regardless of success or error case

    });
}
```

My concern is that if the acceptor socket gets into an error state, the above code will be in an infinite loop of continuously logging the failure, enqueuing a new attempt, ad infinitum. Thus, burning up a core and filling up a log file needlessly.

Which is the better assumption:

1. async_accept calls should never fail on valid sockets. Don't worry about the above code since you diligently checked for errors in initializing the socket and tested your code.
2. async_accept calls can fail, but it never makes sense to retry them, so just close this socket and get out of the retry loop.
3. async_accept calls can have transient failures.  Check the error
   code to determine if it's worth retrying.

If #3 above is the correct assumption, what are the recommended error codes to check for?  And if the error is transient (such as low machine resources, out of handles, etc...) does it make sense to wait a few seconds before retrying so that the thread doesn't burn a core?

*Update*: For what it's worth. My primary platforms are Mac and Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can network layers have transient problems that are worth retrying? Yes.

However, linux `accept` errors are returned from the pending connection list (backlog), whereas e.g. BSD reports them directly.

> ```
>   Error handling
>        Linux accept() (and accept4()) passes already-pending network errors
>        on the new socket as an error code from accept().  This behavior
>        differs from other BSD socket implementations.  For reliable
>        operation the application should detect the network errors defined
>        for the protocol after accept() and treat them like EAGAIN by
>        retrying.  In the case of TCP/IP, these are ENETDOWN, EPROTO,
>        ENOPROTOOPT, EHOSTDOWN, ENONET, EHOSTUNREACH, EOPNOTSUPP, and
>        ENETUNREACH.
> ```

Other conditions that don't apply with Asio's `async_connect` are e.g. `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN`, `EFAULT`.

> See `boost::asio::error` for the corresponding `error_code` names: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/asio/error.hpp

Otherwise go through the list of system errors [documented](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) and see which you think are worth handling explicitly.

In my code I usually just end the chain:

```
_acceptor->async_accept([this](const boost::system::error_code& ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock) {
    if (ec) {
        LogErrorCode(ec);
    } else {
        HandleNewConnection(s);
        StartNextAccept();
    }
});
```

To which my server would just reinitialize the listener (`acceptor` in Asio speak). Of course, that itself might fail, to which the server would probably shutdown.

You may or may not have QoS requirements that prompt you to handle individual conditions differently.

Ultimately, re-initializing the acceptor might be more robust, e.g. when network configuration changed?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think of the case where the client had reset his connection before accept was called on the server. My primary platform is Mac and to a lesser degree Windows 10. Mac's man page lists a specific set of errors for accept and so does Windows docs. So I think it's going to come down to a best effort of identifying transient errors vs fatal errors to decide whether or not to enqueue a new connection vs. re-initialize.

Comment: The `EOPNOTSUPP` one is a head-scratcher for me. One part of the Linux man page says to treat it like `EAGAIN`, and another part says it's a programmer error ("socket is not of type SOCK_STREAM").

Comment: @EmileCormier I never noticed that. I would always consider it programmer error. Could it be due to intermittent traffic controls (traffic shaping firewalls?). Happy you are finding these posts though - I saw your latest question the other day. Hoping you will find what you need!

Comment: @sehe I only found this question today after I posted my question yesterday. I had do to some deep dives into Asio, NGINX, and Apache code to see what they're doing, and my head is about to explode. Network programming code is hard to read if you're not the one who wrote it!

Comment: @sehe `EOPNOTSUPP` is emitted when the "socket is not of type SOCK_STREAM". But Asio's strong typing of socket types should make that impossible anyway if I don't use the socket constructor that takes a native socket handle. Therefore, I think I would prefer to treat it as `EAGAIN` like the man page suggests so that a malicious client doesn't crash the whole server by triggering an `EOPNOTSUPP` error. I've tried poking around the Linux Kernel code to understand when certain errors are returned, but that was an exercise in madness.

Comment: @sehe I've ended up answering my own question. Here it is if you care to read and critique it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76958333/245265