# Which socket accept() errors are fatal?

Tags: sockets, boost, network-programming, posix, boost-asio

I am writing a TCP server program in C++ using Boost.Asio, which uses POSIX sockets under the hood in Linux. I have everything working with a loop that continually accepts new connections and spawns server-side sessions with sockets that are initialized upon the successful completion of [`ip::tcp::acceptor::async_accept`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload2.html) (which is a wrapper around the POSIX [accept](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html) function for you C programmers out there).

Of course, the `async_accept` operation can emit an error code. Upon receiving such error codes, I log them, and continue the accept loop indefinitely until the program is terminated.

I would like to classify the errors in two categories:

1. "Non-fatal" errors that are entirely due to the client (e.g. disconnecting, protocol violation). When these occur, the program should continue listening for new client connections. If the program doesn't continue in these cases, then one misbehaving client can effectively DoS the whole system.
2. "Fatal" errors that are due to programming error or bad server configuration. When these occur, the program should break out of the listening loop and terminate.

How can I tell if an error code belongs to either of my so-called "fatal" and "non-fatal" categories? Is there an open-source application/library out there that already figured this out, so that I can peruse it for inspiration? It doesn't need to use Boost.Asio; something that directly uses (or wraps) POSIX sockets would be useful as well.

What makes matters more complicated is that I'd like my program to be portable, but Linux would be my primary target.

---

**ADDENDUM: This question also applies to C programs that use the POSIX API directly.** Boost.Asio is a low-level wrapper around the POSIX API and passes most underlying POSIX error codes intact.

**ADDENDUM2**: I was asked in the comments to provide example code. Here is the [Boost.Asio TCP echo server example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) modified to break the listening loop upon what I call a "fatal" error. The `server::is_fatal_error` function is where I need help. Note that I know the mechanics of comparing `boost::system::error_code` to error conditions. It's the list of actual error conditions that I'm not sure of.

```cpp
//
// async_tcp_echo_server.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2023 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//
// *** Modified by Emile Cormier for discussion purposes ***

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <system_error>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session
  : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
  session(tcp::socket socket) : socket_(std::move(socket)) {}

  void start() {do_read();}

private:
  void do_read()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec)
            do_write(length);
        });
  }

  void do_write(std::size_t length)
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
          if (!ec)
            do_read();
        });
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, short port)
    : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    do_accept();
  }

private:
  static bool is_fatal_error(boost::system::error_code ec)
  {
    // *** How do I classify the error as fatal so that it bails out ***
    // *** of the listen loop? ***
    return false; // Return something so that it compiles.
  }
    
  void do_accept()
  {
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
          }
          else if (is_fatal_error(ec))
          {
            // Break out of listening loop if error is due to problem
            // on server side (e.g. misconfiguration)
            std::cerr << "Fatal error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            throw std::system_error{ec};
          }

          do_accept();
        });
  }

  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: async_tcp_echo_server <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    server s(io_context, std::atoi(argv[1]));
    io_context.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

**ADDENDUM 3**: One of the comments made me realize that there's another category of errors I need to consider: when the `accept` function fails due to the server being overloaded (which is not the client's fault). I should not break out of the listening loop in those circumstances either.

Comment: Experience. Testing. Lots and lots of exposure to real-world conditions. Many of these are subjective, so there's no hard and fast rules here. I'd advise testing your server under extreme conditions, like heavy load, with clients going through a proxy that imposes severe packet loss, etc.

Comment: Why have you (28.3K reputation) tagged your question with C whereas the question is about C++?

Comment: "How can I tell if an error code belongs to either of my so-called "normal" and "abnormal" categories?" - That's difficult. Some errors are easy; like the client disconnecting before sending their first message. Some are hard; like the client doing what it should, but your server behaving incorrectly. And then you have situations like dropped packets causing timeouts etc. You can't always put things into two buckets.

Comment: @273K I tagged it C because C programs that use POSIX socket API directly would be facing the same dilemma as I am. Boost.Asio passes the low-level socket error codes intact. I (and others) could benefit from the knowledge of network programmers who use C. As I'm typing this, I have other tab open with the NGINX source code (written in C) that I'm studying in an attempt to answer my own question.

Comment: @273K, also, my question is not about C++ per se, it's about POSIX and sockets. C++ happens to be the language I'm using for my program. If anything, perhaps I should remove the C++ tag (alongside the C tag) as my question is almost language-agnostic as long as the underlying network library passes the POSIX error codes intact.

Comment: @tadman If that's the case, then it's pretty sad that being able to know what errors to expect has become sorcery.

Comment: POSIX and sockets are not parts of C. If we continue your thought then win32 also should have been tagged. Maybe [tag:network-programming] is worth to pick.

Comment: @273K, fine. But POSIX and sockets are not parts of C++ either. So I'm removing all language tags.

Comment: Start by reading how Posix socket functions document their error handling. For instance, if `accept()` fails for any reason other than a client disconnecting while still in the queue before `accept()` could return it, then bail out. But if an accepted client fails for any reason, there is no need to stop the accept loop.

Comment: It's not so much sorcery as entirely situational. If you're using modern techniques you probably won't even be using low-level socket calls like in the good old days, you'll be using an abstraction layer that helps manage a lot of this for you, especially the part involving kqueue/epoll/whatever newfangled async mechanism comes along next.

Comment: Remember, problems can occur anywhere in the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), and the number of combinations of layers here is effectively infinite, meaning no two application swill be subjected to the same specific set of errors. If you'd like to learn from experience, look at how battle-hardened applications like Nginx handle their network stack. There are many open-source projects with a full record of the problems they've encountered and the solutions they found.

Comment: @tadman As I've written in my question, I'm using Boost.Asio as the abstraction layer, but it doesn't classify the error codes in way that lets me know if I can continue with the listening loop. I can't be the first one who's faced this problem. I'm indeed currently perusing the NGINX source code in an attempt to answer my own question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau _But if an accepted client fails for any reason, there is no need to stop the accept loop._ That's indeed what I'm currently doing. It's when the accept operation itself fails that I'm uncertain when to bail out of the loop. For example, if the user attempts to launch the server using a port that's already in use, I don't want the loop to be flooding the log with millions of the same error message.

Comment: @RemyLebeau _For instance, if accept() fails for any reason other than a client disconnecting while still in the queue before accept() could return it, then bail out._ The client disconnecting is not the only reason why I should continue the listening loop. If accept fails due to a protocol error (a hacker intentionally sending bogus TCP frames), it would become a DoS if I make the server bail out in that situation. Yes, I should also block IPs that cause frequent protocol errors, but that's an improvement I'll backlog for later.

Comment: I suggest to add example code to the question and ask about specific functions and their error handling. Servers are often implemented in a simple way while DoS protection is implemented by specialized programs like fail2ban in combination with a firewall.

Comment: @Bodo, I'm not sure how example code would help, but I've provided some anyway in my latest edit. In the end, what I need is a list of error codes that correspond to what I call an "abnormal" error where the server should cease listening for new connections. Perhaps "fatal" error would be a better term.

Comment: @EmileCormier If a TCP handshake is not complete, `accept()` will simply not return that connection to you. Only fully complete connections are returned by `accept()`, and then you have a new socket descriptor for it, so `accept()` is hands-off at that point and free to go back to handling the backlog. A DoS attack would happen at a lower level than your code can handle, the OS/socket stack would have to handle it instead. That is what a good firewall is meant to prevent

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah, that cleared up misconceptions that I had about `accept()`. I must admit that sockets are like magic pipes to me, and I've never dug down into how operating systems implement them, other than the usual basic theory taught at universities (which was long ago for me).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you enlighten me in what case the `EPROTO` error is returned? The [Open Group docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html) mention: _for example, the STREAMS protocol stack has not been initialized_, but that doesn't tell in what other instances it can be returned.

Comment: @EmileCormier that same page you linked to says `EPROTO` is "obsolescent" (ie, soon to be obsolete) for `accept()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah yes, missed it. Sorry for bothering you with something I should have read myself.

Comment: Here's a blog post discussing the very same problem that I'm describing. Sadly there's no easy answer there: https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/AcceptErrnoProblem

Comment: I would say as a rule of thumb that *every* error other than `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` is fatal *to the listening socket.

Answer (score 3):

I've studied the NGINX [`ngx_event_accept`](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/e5fc65976a479d3ae46f4ffb6334c2851d654234/src/event/ngx_event_accept.c#L21) function to understand how it handles errors from `accept()` system call. Here is a summary of my findings (please correct me if I misunderstood something).

- `EAGAIN`: This is for non-blocking mode and doesn't apply to me when using Boost.Asio's asynchronous API. NGINX does nothing and waits for the next "cycle" to try again.
- `ECONNABORTED`: This occurs when the client disconnects while in the accept queue. NGINX logs this at "error" severity and proceeds to the next socket awaiting to be accepted.
- `EMFILE` and `ENFILE`: The per-process or system-wide limit on file descriptors has been reached. If I understood the code correctly, NGINX waits for 500 milliseconds before attempting to perform the `accept` operation again. This is logged at "critical" severity. The delay is presumably to give time for some TCP connections to close before listening again.
- All other errors: They are logged at "alert" severity and NGINX will attempt to `accept` again without terminating. I'm guessing this would result in the error log getting flooded if it's not an intermittent problem, but I haven't found anyone mentioning this happening in my internet searches.

---

I've also studied the Apache httpd server code, in particular, the [`ap_unixd_accept`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/a834e62ebf6279ce9e35193151aec809f7f58df1/os/unix/unixd.c#L293) function.

When the [`AcceptErrorsNonFatal`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mpm_common.html#accepterrorsnonfatal) directive is off (which is the default), httpd treats all `accept` errors (except for `EINTR`) as fatal, and gracefully shuts down the child process:

> By default, the child process handling a request will gracefully exit when nearly any socket error occurs during the accept() system call. This is to ensure a potentially unhealthy child process does not try to take on more new connections.

When the `AcceptErrorsNonFatal` directive in on, `ECONNREFUSED`, `ECONNABORTED`, and `ECONNRESET` are **not** treated as fatal.

The [Apache MPM worker](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/worker.html) documentation describes how the server tries to maintain a minimum number of spare worker threads, and the number of running child processes determines the total number of available threads. So if I understand things correctly, a child process that was (gracefully) shutdown due to an `accept` error will eventually be replaced by a new child process if the load stays the same.

---

The use case of a port already being in use would trigger an error in the `bind` system call. I forgot about `bind` in my question because the `boost::ip::tcp::acceptor` constructor has an overload that takes care of this (and throws exceptions upon errors). I need to refactor my code so that I manually open/bind via the `acceptor`, so I can can handle and log errors gracefully.

---

I found this [blog post](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/unix/AcceptErrnoProblem) that describes the same problem I'm facing with `accept()`. They also classify the error codes in two categories:

1. Permanent, due to a programming error
2. Transient (e.g. bad connection)

Sadly, that post has no list of error codes for each of those categories, and the blogger warns about Unix implementations adding extra error codes on top of those specified by POSIX.

---

To get back to my original question, **there are no errors from `accept` that should cause the server to terminate if I am to emulate the behavior of NGINX or Apache httpd**. Since my server will be single-process (but could support thread pools), NGINX would be a better example to emulate.

There are some published error codes for `accept()` that are due to programming error, so I might deviate from NGINX/httpd's behavior and make my program crash when I don't recognize the error code as being transient.

Here is a table of accept error codes from a few OSes, where I attempt to classify each one according the documentation.

| Code | POSIX | Linux | BSD/iOS | Win32 accept | Win32 WSAAccept** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EAGAIN | Asio | Asio | Asio | Asio | Asio? |
| EWOULDBLOCK | Asio | Asio | Asio | Asio | Asio? |
| ECONNABORTED | Asio | Asio | Asio | Asio | Asio? |
| EINTR | Asio | Asio | Asio | Asio | Asio? |
| EPROTO | Asio | Asio | Asio | Asio | Asio? |
| EBADF | Fatal | Fatal | Fatal | Fatal | Fatal |
| ENOTSOCK | Fatal | Fatal | Fatal | Fatal | Fatal |
| EOPNOTSUPP | Fatal | Retry* | Fatal | Fatal | Fatal |
| EINVAL | Fatal | Fatal | Fatal | Fatal | Fatal |
| EMFILE | Load | Load | Load | Load | Load |
| ENFILE | Load | Load | Load | -- | -- |
| ENOBUFS | Load | Load | Load | Load | Load |
| ENOMEM | Load | Load | Load | Load | Load |
| EPERM | -- | Fwall | -- | -- | -- |
| ENOSR | -- | Load | -- | -- | -- |
| ESOCKTNOSUPPORT | -- | Fatal | -- | -- | -- |
| EPROTONOSUPPORT | -- | Fatal | -- | -- | -- |
| ETIMEDOUT | -- | Retry? | -- | -- | -- |
| ENETDOWN | -- | Down | -- | Down | Down |
| ENOPROTOOPT | -- | Down | -- | -- | -- |
| EHOSTDOWN | -- | Down/Retry | -- | -- | -- |
| ENONET | -- | Down | -- | -- | -- |
| EHOSTUNREACH | -- | Down/Retry | -- | -- | -- |
| ENETUNREACH | -- | Down | -- | -- | -- |
| EFAULT | -- | -- | Fatal | Fatal | Fatal |
| WSANOTINITIALISED | -- | -- | -- | Fatal | Fatal |
| ECONNRESET | -- | -- | -- | Retry | Retry |
| EINPROGRESS | -- | -- | -- | n/a | n/a |
| EACCESS | -- | -- | -- | -- | Fatal |
| ECONNREFUSED | -- | -- | -- | -- | Retry |
| WSTRY_AGAIN | -- | -- | -- | -- | Retry |

Legend:

| Label | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| Asio | Consumed by Asio |
| Down | Transient network down error |
| Fatal | Programming error |
| Fwall | Firewall forbids connection (could be fatal or transient) |
| Load | Transient high load error |
| Retry | Brief transient error |

The Linux man page for `accept()` has this note on error handling:

> Linux **accept**() (and **accept4**()) passes already-pending network errors on the new socket as an error code from **accept**(). This behavior differs from other BSD socket implementations. For reliable operation the application should detect the network errors defined for the protocol after **accept**() and treat them like **EAGAIN** by retrying. In the case of TCP/IP, these are **ENETDOWN**, **EPROTO**, **ENOPROTOOPT**, **EHOSTDOWN**, **ENONET**, **EHOSTUNREACH**, **EOPNOTSUPP**, and **ENETUNREACH**.

(*) The `EOPNOTSUPP` code in the Linux man page is puzzling. The above paragraph says to treat it like `EAGAIN`, but in the list below it says "The referenced socket is not of type SOCK_STREAM", which would be a programmer error. Asio's strong typing should make passing the wrong socket type impossible if I don't use the socket constructor that takes a native socket handle.

(**) Asio actually uses `AcceptEx`, but the docs for that function don't list its error codes. I instead listed the error codes for `WSAAccept`, should `AcceptEx` happen to be implemented in terms of `WSAAccept`.

For the "network down" type of error codes, I think it would be prudent to introduce a delay before reattempting, like what NGINX does for the `EMFILE` and `ENFILE` errors.

When it comes to `EAGAIN`, `EWOULDBLOCK`, `ECONNABORTED`, and `EINTR`, `boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::async_accept` already handles them internally and retries the accept operation without emitting an error. This behavior for `ECONNABORTED` can be overridden with the [`enable_connection_aborted`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/enable_connection_aborted.html) special socket option. `async_accept` also treats an `EPROTO` error the same as `ECONNABORTED`. The function where this happens can be found [here](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/89b0a4138a92883ae2514be68018a6c837a5b65f/asio/include/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp#L228).

`async_accept` emits a `boost::asio::error::already_open` error [here](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/89b0a4138a92883ae2514be68018a6c837a5b65f/asio/include/asio/detail/impl/reactive_socket_service_base.ipp#L270) if the socket is already open.

---

Putting all this information together, I've come up with this function (untested) to classify an error code returned by `async_accept`:

```cpp
TcpAcceptErrorCategory classifyAcceptError(boost::system::error_code ec,
                                           bool treatUnknownErrorsAsFatal)
{
    namespace sys = boost::system;

    // Check for transient errors due to heavy load.
    if (   ec == std::errc::no_buffer_space
        || ec == std::errc::not_enough_memory
        || ec == std::errc::too_many_files_open
        || ec == std::errc::too_many_files_open_in_system
#if defined(__linux__)
        || ec == sys::error_code{ENOSR, sys::system_category()}
#endif
        )
    {
        return TcpAcceptErrorCategory::resources;
    }

    // Check for network outagage errors.
#if defined(__linux__)
    if (   ec == std::errc::network_down
        || ec == std::errc::network_unreachable
        || ec == std::errc::no_protocol_option // "Protocol not available"
        || ec == std::errc::operation_not_permitted // Denied by firewall
        || ec == sys::error_code{ENONET, sys::system_category()})
    {
        return TcpAcceptErrorCategory::network;
    }
#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
    if (ec == std::errc::network_down)
        return TcpAcceptErrorCategory::network;
#endif

    // Check for other transient errors. Asio already takes care of
    // EAGAIN, EWOULDBLOCK, ECONNABORTED, EPROTO, and EINTR.
#if defined(__linux__)
    if (   ec == std::errc::host_unreachable
        || ec == std::errc::operation_not_supported
        || ec == std::errc::timed_out
        || ec == sys::error_code{EHOSTDOWN, sys::system_category()})
    {
        return TcpAcceptErrorCategory::retry;
    }
#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
    if (   ec == std::errc::connection_refused
        || ec == std::errc::connection_reset
        || ec == sys::error_code{WSATRY_AGAIN, sys::system_category()})
    {
        return TcpAcceptErrorCategory::retry;
    }
#endif

    if (treatUnknownErrorsAsFatal)
        return TcpAcceptErrorCategory::fatal;

    // Check for programming errors
    if (   ec == boost::asio::error::already_open
        || ec == std::errc::bad_file_descriptor
        || ec == std::errc::not_a_socket
        || ec == std::errc::invalid_argument
#if !defined(__linux__)
        || ec == std::errc::operation_not_supported
#endif
#if defined(BSD) || defined(__APPLE__)
        || ec == std::errc::bad_address // EFAULT
#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
        || ec == std::errc::bad_address // EFAULT
        || ec == std::errc::permission_denied
        || ec == sys::error_code{WSANOTINITIALISED, sys::system_category()}
#endif
        )
    {
        return TcpAcceptErrorCategory::fatal;
    }

    return TcpAcceptErrorCategory::retry;
}
```

I hope these findings help others faced with a similar predicament.