# How to determine if boost::asio::io_context is run out of the work?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I'm using boost::asio::io_context and async_accept to process many clients request.

but when I did a telnet testing, the python script as below, the script will repeatedly send telnet packet to boos::asio. I launched 10 scripts instance trying to send request to server, but after running two hours, boost::asio::io_context in server seems run out of work, which is no longer accept any client.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urCII.png)

```py
host = "192.168.16.178"
port = 12345

while True:
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet()
    tn.open(host, port)
    
    command = "show interfaces"
    
    tn.write(command.encode('ascii')+b'\n')
    
    
    tn.close()
    
    time.sleep(3);
```

```cpp
int ClientManager::Init()
{
    if (this->_listenPort != 0)
    {
        desinit(0);

        _clientAcceptor = new ip::tcp::acceptor(_ioContext, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v6(), _listenPort));

        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address option(true);
        _clientAcceptor->set_option(option);
        _clientAcceptor->listen();

        AsyncAccept();
    }

    _threadSvc = std::thread(&ClientManager::Svc, this);

    return 0;
}


void ClientManager::AcceptHandler(const boost::system::error_code ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket)
{   
    if (ec)
    {
        console->error(PACK("Error code {}, msg:{}"), ec.value(), ec.message());
        Loge( "Error code {}, msg:{}", ec.value(), ec.message());

        return;
    }

    auto client = std::make_shared<ClientBridge>(std::move(socket));
    client->GetConnection();    

    Logi( "Got Connection from :{},port:{},use cnt:{}", client->PeerName(), client->PeerPort(), client.use_count());

    //继续监听
    AsyncAccept();
}


void ClientManager::AsyncAccept()
{
    if (_ioContext.stopped())
    {
        _ioContext.restart();
        Loge("_ioContext.restart1");
        _ioContext.run();
        Loge("_ioContext.restart");
    }

    _clientAcceptor->async_accept([this](boost::system::error_code ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket) { AcceptHandler(ec, std::move(socket)); });
}


void** ClientManager::Svc()**
{
    Logi( "svc is being...");

    _ioContext.run();

    
    **Logi( "svc is end");**
}
```

In ClientManager::Svc() ,_ioContext.stopped() was never triggered.
and the log Logi( "svc is end"); never be printed after lauching 10 telnet script for a long time.

my question is:
How to properly handle io_context() status, make io_context() continuously accept client request when  run the above telnet scripts for a long time?

Comment: Use `executor_work_guard'  to keep the context 'alive'.   You can allocate one using new, keeping it in a safe place, and then delete it when you exit your application.

Comment: Thank you very much.   As my telnet testing,  io_context.run() seems blocked, not actually QUIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In ClientManager::Svc() ,_ioContext.stopped() was never triggered.

That makes sense. You trigger `AsyncAccept` once manually, when the service is never stopped. Then it is only triggered from `AcceptHandler` which is the completion handler for `async_accept`.

Completion handlers are never invoked after the context is stopped, by definition: it's what stopping means: the service stops invoking handlers.

### Deep Dive

You don't show your main code. Nothing in your code actually calls `_ioContext.stop` - ever. This means that

- your `main` **MUST** contain an infinite loop of some kind (otherwise `_svcThread` destructor will throw because it isn't joined)
- `ClientManager` will only run out of work when

  - (a) all connections that have been accepted closed on their own accord AND
  - (b) the accept loop is broken. This happens when `ec` indicates an error, so it should be in the console and the error log

> *As a side note, code not shown might raise an exception from a handler (see [Should the exception thrown by boost::asio::io_service::run() be caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500818/should-the-exception-thrown-by-boostasioio-servicerun-be-caught)). This is not your problem since you would see a abnormal program termination because the exception is not handled on the thread*

Regardless, your attempts to `restart` the service will never be called because the service is not invoking any handlers *when stopped*. Instead, avoid running out of work. If the server fails (e.g. because the network is reconfigured or something) start a new one entirely.

Other notes:

- There's quite a bit unnecessary use of pointers. Use of raw pointers, `new` and `delete` are usually bad ideas in modern C++
- The choice for `tcp::v6()` seems a bit arbitrary here (the sample client never connects over tcpv6)
- Two-phase init is a code smell (`Init()` should really be the constructor). What is the "upside" of re-using the same ClientManager if it... failed? Instead just instantiate a new one when that happens.
- instead of using a `work_guard` (which can be forgotten), consider using `asio::thread_pool` which has the logic built in. You can join it in the destructor.
- Better yet, decouple the execution context from the service objects

### Simple Fixes

Here's the original listing with the missing code re-imagined:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3a6a302022bd6df)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::literals;

static inline constexpr auto PACK(char const* fmt) { return fmt; }

struct Console {
    void info(char const* fmt, auto const&... args) const {
        fmt::print(fmt::runtime("INF\t"s + fmt + "\n"), args...);
    }
    void error(char const* fmt, auto const&... args) const {
        fmt::print(fmt::runtime("ERR\t"s + fmt + "\n"), args...);
    }
};
static auto console = std::make_shared<Console>();
void        Logi(char const* fmt, auto const&... args) { console->info(fmt, args...); }
void        Loge(char const* fmt, auto const&... args) { console->error(fmt, args...); }

struct ClientBridge : std::enable_shared_from_this<ClientBridge>{
    ClientBridge(tcp::socket s) : _socket(std::move(s)) {}
    void GetConnection() {
        auto ep = _socket.remote_endpoint();
        _peerName = ep.address().to_string();
        _peerPort = ep.port();

        do_read();
    }
    std::string PeerName() const { return _peerName; }
    uint16_t    PeerPort() const { return _peerPort; }

    ~ClientBridge() { Logi("Client {}:{} disconnect", _peerName, _peerPort); }

  private:
    void do_read() {
        async_read_until( //
            _socket, boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(_receive), "\n",
            [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                auto msg = _receive.substr(0, n - 1);
                _receive.erase(0, n);

                console->info("Received from {}:{} '{}' with ec:{}", _peerName, _peerPort, msg, ec.message());

                if (!ec) {
                    send("echo: " + std::move(msg) + "\n");
                    do_read();
                }
            });
    }

    void send(std::string msg) {
        _outbox.push_back(std::move(msg));
        if (_outbox.size()==1)
            do_write_loop();
    }

    void do_write_loop() {
        if (_outbox.empty())
            return;

        async_write( //
            _socket, boost::asio::buffer(_outbox.front()),
            [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                console->info("Written to {}:{} {} bytes with ec:{}", _peerName, _peerPort, n, ec.message());
                if (!ec) {
                    _outbox.pop_front();
                    do_write_loop();
                }
            });
    }

    tcp::socket _socket;
    std::string _peerName;
    uint16_t    _peerPort;

    std::string             _receive;
    std::deque<std::string> _outbox;
};

struct ClientManager {
    ClientManager(uint16_t port) : _listenPort(port) {}
    int Init();

    void AcceptHandler(error_code ec, tcp::socket socket);
    void AsyncAccept();
    void Svc();

  private:
    boost::asio::io_context _ioContext;
    tcp::acceptor           _clientAcceptor{_ioContext};
    std::thread             _threadSvc;
    uint16_t                _listenPort = 0;

    void desinit(int) {}
};

int ClientManager::Init() {
    if (this->_listenPort != 0) {
        desinit(0);

        _clientAcceptor = tcp::acceptor(_ioContext, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), _listenPort));

        _clientAcceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        _clientAcceptor.listen();
        AsyncAccept();
    }

    _threadSvc = std::thread(&ClientManager::Svc, this);

    return 0;
}

void ClientManager::AcceptHandler(error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
    if (ec) {
        console->error(PACK("Error code {}, msg:{}"), ec.value(), ec.message());
        Loge("Error code {}, msg:{}", ec.value(), ec.message());

        return;
    }

    auto client = std::make_shared<ClientBridge>(std::move(socket));
    client->GetConnection();

    Logi("Got Connection from :{},port:{},use cnt:{}", client->PeerName(), client->PeerPort(),
         client.use_count());

    AsyncAccept();
}

void ClientManager::AsyncAccept() {
    if (_ioContext.stopped()) {
        _ioContext.restart();
        Loge("_ioContext.restart1");
        _ioContext.run();
        Loge("_ioContext.restart");
    }

    _clientAcceptor.async_accept(
        make_strand(_ioContext), //
        [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) { AcceptHandler(ec, std::move(socket)); });
}

void ClientManager::Svc() {
    Logi("svc is being...");

    _ioContext.run();

    Logi("svc is end");
}

int main() {
    ClientManager server(12345);
    server.Init();

    while (true)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
}
```

Showing it works with concurrent connections and re-connecting after all connections closed:

[image]

Showing it works under heavy load:

[image]

Note that much of the slowness is due to console logging.

### TOO MANY OPEN FILES

Then when I flipped the test case around to instead make many separate connections and minimizing console IO for speed:

```
(while read line < words; do (sleep .$RANDOM; nc localhost 12345 -w 1 <<< "$line" 2>&1 >/dev/null )& done; time wait)
```

Now we can SEE the problem. As I predicted above, the accept error is correctly logged:

```
ERR Error code 24, msg:Too many open files
ERR Error code 24, msg:Too many open files
```

After which we can see all previous connections completing:

```
INF Received from 127.0.0.1:39820 'asparagus's' with ec:Success
INF Written to 127.0.0.1:39820 18 bytes with ec:Success
INF Received from 127.0.0.1:58864 '' with ec:End of file
INF Client 127.0.0.1:58864 disconnect
INF Received from 127.0.0.1:58880 '' with ec:End of file
INF Client 127.0.0.1:58880 disconnect
   ... 2027 more clients disconnecting
INF Client 127.0.0.1:39812 disconnect
INF Received from 127.0.0.1:39792 '' with ec:End of file
INF Client 127.0.0.1:39792 disconnect
```

And indeed, after the last connection is gone, the service ran out of work:

```
INF svc is end
```

The cause here is the OS running out of file descriptors. You might want to

- raise the per-process or systemwide limits of open files
- "be smart" - e.g. wait a bit before trying again. See here for an excellent breakdown of possible accept errors and how to handle them in serious servers: [Which socket accept() errors are fatal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76955978/which-socket-accept-errors-are-fatal/76958333#76958333)

### Simplifications and Improvements

Doing some of the simplifications discussed above:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fd0f70813ab4181)**

```cpp
#define NDEBUG
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <fmt/format.h>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct Console {
    void info(std::string const& fmt, auto const&... args) const { fmt::print(fmt::runtime("INF\t" + fmt + "\n"), args...); }
    void warn(std::string const& fmt, auto const&... args) const { fmt::print(fmt::runtime("WARN\t" + fmt + "\n"), args...); }
    void error(std::string const& fmt, auto const&... args) const { fmt::print(fmt::runtime("ERR\t" + fmt + "\n"), args...); }
};
static auto console = std::make_shared<Console>();
void Logi(std::string const&, auto const&...) { /*console->info(fmt, args...);*/ }
void Logw(std::string const& fmt, auto const&... args) { console->warn(fmt, args...); }
void Loge(std::string const& fmt, auto const&... args) { console->error(fmt, args...); }

struct ClientBridge : std::enable_shared_from_this<ClientBridge>{
    ClientBridge(tcp::socket s) : _socket(std::move(s)) {}
    void Start() {
        auto ep   = _socket.remote_endpoint();
        _peerName = ep.address().to_string();
        _peerPort = ep.port();
        Logi("New connection from:{}, port:{}", _peerName, _peerPort);

        do_read();
    }

    ~ClientBridge() { Logi("Client {}:{} disconnect", _peerName, _peerPort); }

  private:
    void do_read() {
        async_read_until( //
            _socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(_receive), "\n",
            [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                auto msg = _receive.substr(0, n - 1);
                _receive.erase(0, n);

                Logi("Received from {}:{} '{}' with ec:{}", _peerName, _peerPort, msg, ec.message());

                if (!ec) {
                    send("echo: " + std::move(msg) + "\n");
                    do_read();
                }
            });
    }

    void send(std::string msg) {
        _outbox.push_back(std::move(msg));
        if (_outbox.size()==1)
            do_write_loop();
    }

    void do_write_loop() {
        if (_outbox.empty())
            return;

        async_write( //
            _socket, asio::buffer(_outbox.front()),
            [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                Logi("Written to {}:{} {} bytes with ec:{}", _peerName, _peerPort, n, ec.message());
                if (!ec) {
                    _outbox.pop_front();
                    do_write_loop();
                }
            });
    }

    tcp::socket _socket;
    std::string _peerName;
    uint16_t    _peerPort;

    std::string             _receive;
    std::deque<std::string> _outbox;
};

struct ClientManager {
    ClientManager(uint16_t port) : _listenPort(port) {
        _clientAcceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        _clientAcceptor.listen();
        AsyncAccept();
    }

    ~ClientManager() { _ioc.join(); }

  private:
    void AsyncAccept() {
        _clientAcceptor.async_accept(make_strand(_ioc), [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
            if (ec) {
                Loge("Error code {}, msg:{}", ec.value(), ec.message());

                if (ec == asio::error::no_descriptors) {
                    Logw("Waiting 500ms");
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
                    AsyncAccept();
                }
            } else {
                std::make_shared<ClientBridge>(std::move(socket))->Start();
                AsyncAccept();
            }
        });
    }

    asio::thread_pool _ioc;
    uint16_t          _listenPort;
    tcp::acceptor     _clientAcceptor{_ioc, {{}, _listenPort}};
};

int main() {
    ClientManager server(12345);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
} // destructor joins - until the context ran out of work
```

This solves the accept issue by delaying the accept (and logging that), spreads connections across a threadpool, and makes it so that the destructor of `ClientManager` only returns when the server is actually done.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.  For ec == asio::error::no_descriptors this scenario, is there any method to release file descriptors? I mean, if we use wait 500ms, might not be effective.

Comment: You have to study your applications requirements and the limits the server uses. Sometimes your server may end up with many _lingering sockets_ (this is related to TCP security features as far as I know). This is something that may need to be addressed at the client side. There are no ways to "release the descriptors" when they're being used - unless just closing connections counts. Also, that's another question that probably already has many answers on this site.